# Move log files that are more than 10mb in size from source folder to another directory using Batch Commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

What is the best way to move files that are more than 10mb in size from a specific folder to another directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "sourceFolder=%cd%"
    set "targetFolder=%cd%\target"
    set "minSize=10485760"

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%sourceFolder%" "%sourceFolder%" /l /is /nocopy /njh /njs /nc /ns /ndl /min:%minsize%
    ') do echo move /y "%%~fa" "%targetFolder%"
```

This uses the `robocopy` command (that has not been used directly to move the files as it will not use a move operation but first copy to target and then delete the source) to get a list of files with the indicated minimum size. This list is processed with a `for /f` command and for each file a `move` operation is executed.

`move` commands are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.